# disable bluetooth profiles

Tags: settings, bluetooth

On an android 13 device, what is the easiest way, without rooting it, to disable all bluetooth profiles, besides a select few?
The point is to limit what sorts of things nearby/paired devices can do with the android device.

Some searching found these, which might be relevant...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866179/programmatically-enable-disable-bluetooth-profiles

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/bluetooth/BluetoothProfileManager

https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/DISA_STIG_Google_Android_12_COPE_v1r1-AirWatch.audit:ca70a16d7e95fe803576202e1f4ed03e

However, each one is unfamiliar territory, and was just looking to know what would be the most expedient method to accomplish the task (whether per above or otherwise), along with some practical guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Bump. nudge. anyone?